# Is there a way to click on a bootstrap thumbnail and open up a file chooser?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to do this? I have a couple of image previews and I wanted to click on the thumbnails and select the images, instead of having a button named "Select File".

Is there a way to add an `<input type="file" />` to a thumbnail and make this happen?

I'm following this current snippet:

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /></div>
  <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is like this. first create a hidden ul to accumulate all the selected files and an hidden input file element

HTML

```
<ul class="hiddenItem">

</ul>

<input type="file" class="hiddenItem" id="filechoose" />
```

CSS

```
.hiddenItem{
    display: none;
}
```

And then use jquery like this

```
$(function(){
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
      $("#filechoose").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

This will open up the select file dialog. You'll have to grab the file and add it to the ul. After that when you want to pass the files to your server script, you can just pass the ul.

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb5Ap/)